# How can this same result be achieved via a foreach loop in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to make a `DeleteRecord()` that takes any number of `String[][]` type arguments. I have made a sort of test function just to see what kind of logice iwould need to apply to make that function. I made it work but I want to use a foreach loop. how can I do that. I have this code:

```
public void testSomething(String[][]... enteredStrings) {
        for (int i = 0; i < enteredStrings[0].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < enteredStrings[0][i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("i -> " + i + " " + "j -> " + j + " " + enteredStrings[0][i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I know how to make foreach loop in java but I can't do it with a multidimensional array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's three dimensional my friend

Comment: If you intend on modifying the elements (since I see that you want to make a `DeleteRecord()`), your innermost loop should not be a foreach loop, otherwise the arrays won't be modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through the `String[]`s in the outer array of strings-arrays:

```
for (String[] arr : enteredStrings) {
    for (String str : arr) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The biggest hitch with a for-each loop given the provided code will be the third `println`. You are using the indices there, so if you need to maintain that line the way it is, you'll have to start with this and continue to track where you are.

Comment: @SLaks i think you are forgetting the part where `testSomething()` is a variadic type

Comment: I think Thomas is right here.  Any time you need to keep track of the indices, you might as well just use a standard for loop.

Comment: I think enteredStrings is actually a 3d array.

Comment: yes it is. Eclipse shows a tooltip like this String[][][] enteredStrings. and my code body also shows that.

Comment: Further.. i do not need to keep track of indices.

Comment: @Prometheus87: Then you need three nested loops.

Comment: got that. now the problem of on index getting printed at one time arises, whereas i want both index values to print next to each other

Comment: If you need to index, you shouldn't be using a foreach in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For a 3D array with your setup the code below will print the contents of the array. However, I'm not sure how you get the indices with a for each.

```
public void test2(String[][]... enteredStrings){
    for (String[] iii : enteredStrings[0]){
        for (String jjj: iii){
            System.out.println(jjj);
        }
    }
}
```